# How Base58check to Hex Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to convert Base58check to HexString in Dart language?

Like on this site: https://www.btcschools.net/tron/tron_tool_base58check_hex.php

Take this data as an example:

Base58 String: TNNukJf11S9iJr1RmgViE2kr8LdFCBBeVb - this TRON Wallet

Hex String: 41881d16d9cd320c94d93acbbe52128ccd0ff9a7d4

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies:
  hex: ^0.2.0
  bs58check: ^1.0.2
```

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:bs58check/bs58check.dart' as bs58check;
import 'package:hex/hex.dart';

void main() {
  const String base58Address = 'TNNukJf11S9iJr1RmgViE2kr8LdFCBBeVb';
  final Uint8List decodedBase58 = bs58check.decode(base58Address);
  final String encodedHex = HEX.encode(decodedBase58);
  print(encodedHex); // 41881d16d9cd320c94d93acbbe52128ccd0ff9a7d4
}
```